# Loop through fields and break

Tags: awk

My file looks looks like this:

```
1000074493 1D # # # # #
1000098165 1D # # # # #
1000105360 1D # # # # #
1000115763 1D 2D # # # #
1000345208 1D # # # # #
1000470774 1D 2D # 4D # #
1000487544 # # 3D # 5D #
1000499657 1D # # # # #
1000531456 1D # # # # #
1000561333 # # # # 5D #
```

I want to loop per record through fields 2:NF
`print if $NF != #`
and stop reading the line but continue in next line.

In other words,
find the first field after the first which isn't `#`, then print only the first field and that field, and skip to the next line.

So the expected result would be:

```
1000074493 1D
1000098165 1D
1000105360 1D
1000115763 1D
1000345208 1D
1000470774 1D
1000487544 3D
1000499657 1D
1000531456 1D
1000561333 5D
```

My code is:

```
awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {if($i != "#" ) print $1,$i }}' $FILE
```

which gives me:

```
1000074493 1D
1000098165 1D
1000105360 1D
1000115763 1D
1000115763 1D
1000345208 1D
1000470774 1D
1000470774 2D
1000470774 4D
1000487544 3D 
1000487544 5D
1000499657 1D
1000531456 1D
1000561333 5D
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: see: [awk get the nextline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575730/awk-get-the-nextline), or in the docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Next-Statement

Answer (score 2):

Like your original question articulation should already have suggested, the keyword you are looking for is `break`.

```sh
awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if($i != "#" ) { print $1,$i; break }}' "$FILE"
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/hWRM9K

As an aside, avoid [useless uses of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and [use lower case for your private variables,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and [quote file name variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: As these comments are no longer relevant, please remove them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '{gsub(/#/,""); print $1,$2}'  file
1000074493 1D
1000098165 1D
1000105360 1D
1000115763 1D
1000345208 1D
1000470774 1D
1000487544 3D
1000499657 1D
1000531456 1D
1000561333 5D
```

Answer (score 0):

the following applied to your file gave me your expected result

```
awk '{i=2; while ($i == "#") i++; print $1 " " $i}' $FILE
```

Comment: Let `OFS` do the only thing it exists to do - `print $1, $i`.

Answer (score -1):

Found out finally by myself:

```
awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {if($i != "#" )  print $1,$i }}' $FILE|awk '$1 != p {print $1,$2}{p=$1}'
```

if anyone knows how to combine both awk statements in one, it would be appreciated!